How to escape the & character in Cypress environment variable
I use environment variables for my Cypress test execution. If I use a string in an environment variable, which contains an & character, the string gets cut off.
Example:
npx cypress run --spec "xy.js" --env PW="B31G&zL"

Cypress only receives the string "B31G".
I've tried several suggestions to escape the &, but nothing worked.
Does anybody have an idea, how I can escape the & ?
I've tried escaping the & character with \& also with ^& or with \\&.
Furthermore, I've put the whole environment variable under quotes "" and single quotes ''.

Did you try %26?

just tried... doesn't seem to work.

What OS and/or terminal are you using? I just tried setting the variable with the \  character and it received the full string - albeit with the \  included. I also tried it without the \  character, and it was able to get the full string.

Try this - npx cypress run --spec "xy.js" --env PW="B31G^&zL"

There's some discussion here Is there an escape for '&' character in the command prompt? about using ^ as the escape character, and it has some limited success with the env variable you are using.
For reference, there are several methods of passing env vars to Cypress,
Environment Variables

Option #1: configuration file
Option #2: cypress.env.json
Option #3: CYPRESS_*
Option #4: --env
Option #5: Test Configuration


Option #4: --env
You are trying Option #4, and on Windows is works like this:
package.json
"scripts": {
  "cy:run1": "npx cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/ampersand.cy.js --env PW=\"B31G^&zL\""
}

A simple test:
it('passes', () => {
  expect(Cypress.env('PW')).to.eq('B31G&zL')
})



Option #3: CYPRESS_* 
You can also pass it as a general env var with CYPRESS_ prefix, but in the test you need to .trim() the value as it grabs an extra space char.
"scripts": {
  "cy:run2": "SET CYPRESS_PW=B31G^&zL && npx cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/ampersand.cy.js",
}

it('passes', () => {
  expect(Cypress.env('PW').trim()).to.eq('B31G&zL')
})


Option #2: cypress.env.json 
This is the path of "least resistance", just paste the password in and it works as expected.
cypress.env.json
{
  "PW": "B31G&zL"
}

"scripts": {
  "cy:run3": "npx cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/ampersand.cy.js"
}


Thanks for your answer :-)
I need to use option 4 with the --env. Unfortunately, your suggestion still doesn't work. --env PW="B31G^&zL"
Cypress cuts off the string before the &
Only difference to your solution is, that I need to directly call the command from the console and I don't have it in the package.json. I need it this way because of our Test Pipeline.

It works for me. Also if you are just typing directly it also works.
